# bundling errors on server with digital ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, bundle, digital-ocean

I'm having many issues with trying to bundle on digital ocean.

This is what happens when i type in the bundle command

```
Installing bcrypt 3.1.11 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160618-2255-1wegwqh.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling crypt_gensalt.c
compiling crypt.c
compiling crypt_blowfish.c
compiling bcrypt_ext.c
compiling wrapper.c
linking shared-object bcrypt_ext.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/rails/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bcrypt-3.1.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/rails/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/bcrypt-3.1.11/gem_make.out
Using sass 3.4.22
Using bundler 1.12.5
Installing byebug 8.2.5 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160618-2255-r0j1sx.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling threads.c
compiling byebug.c
compiling context.c
compiling locker.c
linking shared-object byebug/byebug.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [byebug.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/rails/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/byebug-8.2.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/rails/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/byebug-8.2.5/gem_make.out
Using callsite 0.0.11
Using sexp_processor 4.7.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
Using thor 0.19.1
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
Installing debug_inspector 0.0.2 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160618-2255-ds4tg3.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling debug_inspector.c
linking shared-object debug_inspector.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [debug_inspector.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/rails/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/debug_inspector-0.0.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/rails/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/debug_inspector-0.0.2/gem_make.out
Using delayed_task 0.2.0
Using orm_adapter 0.5.0
Using multi_json 1.12.0
Using multipart-post 2.0.0
Using equalizer 0.0.11
Using git-version-bump 0.15.1
Using uber 0.0.15
Using hashie 3.4.4
Using multi_xml 0.5.5
Using newrelic_rpm 3.15.2.317
Installing pg 0.18.4 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160618-2255-lkyo3s.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1113:in `block in find_header'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1112:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:47:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/rails/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/rails/admitme/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
Using require_all 1.3.3
Using ruby-progressbar 1.8.0
Using rubyzip 1.2.0
Using tilt 2.0.2
Using spring 1.7.1
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I ahev been following this tutorial to the letter!https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-ruby-on-rails-one-click-application-on-digitalocean

And i've just got to the stage where it asks to run rake tasks.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Thanks
Sam

**edit**
Just tried to do the gem postgresql installa nd received this error:

```
gem install postgresql
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing postgresql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160618-2878-1i8lq34.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.packet_write_wait: Connection to 178.62.49.50: Broken pipe
```

**New error**

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160618-4364-1nty8ik.rb extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-pg
    --without-pg
    --enable-windows-cross
    --disable-windows-cross
    --with-pg-config
    --without-pg-config
    --with-pg_config
    --without-pg_config
    --with-pg-dir
    --without-pg-dir
    --with-pg-include
    --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
    --with-pg-lib
    --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:587:in `try_cpp'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1113:in `block in find_header'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1112:in `find_header'
    from extconf.rb:47:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/pg-0.18.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/pg-0.18.4/gem_make.out
```

Comment: If you have a root shell to the server please install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev packages.... If the message during pg gem instalation dissapear, just look for byebug, bcrypt and debug_inspector system dependencies and install them.

Comment: so just do a gem install postgresql?

Comment: First connect to server and install "apt-get install postgresql-contrib libpq-dev" packages, then try that again with "gem install pg"

Comment: did that, see second edit

Comment: Yes, install "apt-get install build-essential" and try that again.